# What is the probability that a four-digit number formed by randomly selecting four-digits without replacement is greater than $4321$?

Tags: probability

A four-digit number is formed by randomly selecting four digits, without replacement, from the set $D = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$. What is the probability that the resulting number is greater than $4321$?

**Attempt:** The odds of choosing a $5$, $6$, or $7$ are $1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7 = 3/7$.  Then the odds of choosing a $4$ for the first number are $1/7$.  If my second number is $5$, $6$, or a $7$, I know the number will be greater than $4321$. This is $3/6$ so $1/7 \cdot 3/6 = 3/42$.  Then I'm getting stuck.

Comment: Well, if the first digit is $1,2,3,5,6,7$, you are done immediately. If the first digit is $4$, consider the second digit, etc... a little casework will finish the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us what you’ve tried? No offense, but otherwise, it just looks like you’re asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: yes...I've tried the following:

Comment: the odds of choosing a 5, 6, or 7 are 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7 = 3/7

Comment: then the odds of choosing a 4 for the first number are 1/7.  (sorry, I kept hitting enter - I haven't used this site before). if my second number is 5, 6, or a 7 I know the number will be greater than 4321....this is 3/6 so 1/7 * 3/6 = 3/42

Comment: Then I'm getting stuck...

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Your attempt should be included in the question itself rather than the comments, where it might be missed.

Answer (score 2):

What you have done thus far is correct.  That leaves cases in which the first number is $4$ and the second number is $3$.  The probability of first obtaining $4$, then obtaining $3$ is $\frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{42}$.  We now consider two cases: the third digit is larger than $2$ or the third digit is $2$ and the fourth digit is larger than $1$.

*The first digit is $4$, the second digit is $3$, and the third digit is larger than $2$*:  The remaining digits are $1, 2, 5, 6, 7$. Of these, three are larger than $2$. Hence, the probability that the first digit is $4$, the second digit is $3$, and the third digit is larger than $2$ is 
$$\frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{5}$$

*The first digit is $4$, the second digit is $3$, the third digit is $2$, and the fourth digit is larger than $1$*:  Once $4$, $3$, and $2$ have been selected, the remaining digits are $1, 5, 6, 7$, of which three are larger than $1$.  Hence, the probability that the first digit is $4$, the second digit is $3$, the third digit is $2$, and the fourth digit is larger than $1$ is 
$$\frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4}$$

Hence, the probability of randomly selecting a four-digit number without replacement from the set $D = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ that is larger than $4321$ is 
$$\frac{3}{7} + \frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} + \frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I wouldn’t have figured this out in my own.